# How can I find the reason my tkinter is dead?

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I'm trying to make a screen recording program with some interface.
the recording works nice when it's played independently,
but as soon as I put into a function and use as a button command,
tkinter gets dead.
there is no error message, nothing but a dead window.
how can I figure this out?
the code is:

```
import pyautogui
import cv2
import numpy as np
import keyboard
import time
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import messagebox

def record_stop(): 
    keyboard.press_and_release('q')

def screenrec(): #recording program
    resolution = (1920,1080)
    codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    filename = '{}.avi'.format(time.strftime('_%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'))
    fps = 60.0
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, codec, fps, resolution)
    messagebox.showinfo('info', 'Recording start.')

    while True:
        img = pyautogui.screenshot() 
        frame = np.array(img) 
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 

        out.write(frame)
    
       if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
           messagebox.showinfo('info', 'Recording stopped.')
           break
    
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


root = Tk()
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title('Record program')

btnframe = LabelFrame(root, text='Record')
btnframe.pack(fill='x', padx=5, pady=5)

btn_start = Button(btnframe, text='Start recording', width=10, command=screenrec)
btn_start.pack(side='left', padx=5, pady=5)

btn_stop = Button(btnframe, text='Stop recording', width=10, command=record_stop)
btn_stop.pack(side='right', pady=5, padx=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Loops mess with ```tkinter.mainloop()``` you can use ```threading.Thread(target=screenrec).start()```

Comment: @Sujay Thank you for informing me! but I'm kinda new to python, so i don't understand what actually a threading & Thread is. Can you give me an example in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop is blocking tkinter's loop. So make use of threads using the threading module

Here is an example:

```py
import pyautogui
import cv2
import numpy as np
import keyboard
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from threading import Thread

def record_stop(): 
    keyboard.press_and_release('q')

def screenrec(): #recording program
    resolution = (1920,1080)
    codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    filename = '{}.avi'.format(time.strftime('_%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'))
    fps = 60.0
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, codec, fps, resolution)
    messagebox.showinfo('info', 'Recording start.')

    while record:
        img = pyautogui.screenshot() 
        frame = np.array(img) 
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 

        out.write(frame)
    
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
           messagebox.showinfo('info', 'Recording stopped.')
           break
    
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


def switchRec():
    global record
    record = not record
    
    if record:
        btn_start.config(text="Stop recording")
        thread = Thread(target=screenrec)
        thread.setDaemon(True)
        thread.start()
        
    else:
        btn_start.config(text="Start recording")


root = Tk()
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title('Record program')

record = False

btnframe = LabelFrame(root, text='Record')
btnframe.pack(fill='x', padx=5, pady=5)

btn_start = Button(btnframe, text='Start recording', width=10, command=switchRec)
btn_start.pack(side='left', padx=5, pady=5)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please add more explanation to your answer, otherwise it doesn't have a lot of value to future readers, also: I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

Comment: @Matiiss what do you mean by add more explanation? I think it already has a sufficient explanation of the problem and solution. About wildcard imports, I do understand the problems with wildcard imports. I didn't use wildcard import, it was simply copied from the OP's code. I also believe wildcard imports are fine when trying to create small example programs and they don't cause that much of an issue in such cases.

Comment: I actually don't even know, I mean you could explain what you changed in detail, maybe I just explain too much when writing an answer (which is not always needed) so I expect others to do so even though they have done a great job already (sometimes they actually haven't explained anything), the only reason I said that is because there is not that much text compared to code,

Comment: about the imports tho: I disagree for two reasons, first of even in smaller projects one may accidentally import everything from (for example) `tkinter` and `tkinter.ttk` (I have seen that happen that is actually why I am now telling this to everyone), the issue is that both modules have some classes that have the same names but they have slightly different attributes and stuff and then it is kinda hard to debug why this Button class that always had that argument now doesn't have it, second reason is that you should get in habit of doing it the better way especially for newer programmers

Answer (score 0):

While loops mess with `mainloop`. Try this:

```
import multiprocessing
.....
def screenrec(): #recording program
    resolution = (1920,1080)
    codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    filename = '{}.avi'.format(time.strftime('_%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'))
    fps = 60.0
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, codec, fps, resolution)
    messagebox.showinfo('info', 'Recording start.')

    while True:
        img = pyautogui.screenshot() 
        frame = np.array(img) 
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 

        out.write(frame)
    
       if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
           messagebox.showinfo('info', 'Recording stopped.')
           proc.terminate()
           break
    
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def new_process():
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=screenrec)
    proc.start()
btn_start = Button(btnframe, text='Start recording', width=10, command=new_process)
btn_start.pack(side='left', padx=5, pady=5)
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! This code is very simple to use! many thanks for your effort :)